# R - Summation of data frame columns changes data type

Tags: r, types, dataframe

I have a data frame of 15 columns where the first column is an integer and others are numeric. I have to generate a one-liner summary of the sum of all columns except the last one. I need to generate mean of the last column. So, I am doing something as below:

```
summary <- c(sum(df$col1), ... mean(df$col15))
```

The `summary` then appears with values up to two decimal places even for the integer column (first one). I have been trying the `round` function to fix this. I can understand, when different types are added, e.g. `1 + 1.0`. But, in this case, shouldn't the summation maintain the data-type?

Please let me know what am I missing?

Comment: @Frank I was trying to emulate what  the OP was doing instead of doing the `sum` manually for each column.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I guess that's not the core of the question, though. (Presumably, the upvoters read it the same way you did, so it's easy to disagree without the OP giving an example.)

Comment: @Frank I understand it now.  It would have been better for the OP to show an example and expected output

Comment: R doesn't mix data types in the same vector. See https://www.nealgroothuis.name/introduction-to-data-types-and-objects-in-r/

Comment: Your description is confusing.  `first column is an integer and others are numeric` and then `sum of all columns except the last one`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a one-line summary:

```
lst <- c(lapply(df[-ncol(df)], function(x) sum(x)), mean=mean(df[,ncol(df)]))
as.data.frame(lst)
#  int num1 mean
#1  10    6  2.5
```

The output is a data frame that preserves the classes of each vector. If you would like the output to be added to the original data frame you can replace `as.data.frame(lst)` with:

```
names(lst) <- names(df)
rbind(df, lst)
```

If you are trying to get the sum of all integer columns and the mean of numeric columns, go with @Frank's answer.

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(int=1:4, num1=seq(1,2,length.out=4), num2=seq(2,3,length.out=4))
```

Comment: I will try out that one. But, what's wrong with the simple `sum` and `mean`? A vector output is more than enough for this particular case I am working on.

Comment: A vector can only have one type. You can't mix numeric and integer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an adaptation of this?

```
apply(iris[,1:4], 2, sum) / c(rep(1,3), nrow(iris))
```